# Trying to debug an LLVM pass with gdb , opt says too many positional arguments specified?

Tags: debugging, gdb, llvm

I'm trying to debug an LLVM pass with gdb.

I First do `gdb usr/bin/opt` and then

```
run opt -load ~/llvm/build/lib/LLVMHello.so  -hello < ~/llvm examples/trial.bc > /dev/null
```

now this gives the error ->

```
Starting program: /usr/bin/opt opt -load ~/llvm/build/lib/LLVMHello.so  -hello < ~/llvm examples/trial.bc > /dev/null
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
opt: Too many positional arguments specified!
Can specify at most 1 positional arguments: See: /usr/bin/opt -help
[Inferior 1 (process 8000) exited with code 01]
(gdb)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to specify `opt` when running `usr/bin/opt`, try

```
run -load ~/llvm/build/lib/LLVMHello.so  -hello < ~/llvm examples/trial.bc > /dev/null
```

Comment: Sorry for the newbie question but  when I run gdb opt I get 'no debugging symbols found' . Now , opt is an executable in usr/bin and I don't get how to compile opt with the debugging flag..?

Comment: Did you install the just built llvm into usr/bin/opt? Otherwise you'll need to use the one in the build directory. For example, if you used autoconf:

gdb ./builds/build-llvm/Debug+Asserts/bin/opt

provided you did something like this:

mkdir -p ./builds/build-llvm/
cd ./builds/build-llvm
path/to/llvm/configure ; make